# How to use weight in infomap code (Python)?

Tags: python, igraph

I want to use `infomap` to find a community of network. I have a directed and weighted graph. My problem is that the way I use the code, does not consider the weight of the graph, and I have to consider it. This is my code:

```
from igraph import *
import pandas as pd

g1=Graph.Read_Ncol("1.txt",names=("node1","node2","weigths"),weights="if_present",directed=True)

print g1.community_infomap()
```

My input is something like this:

```
0   1   0.9
1   2   0.0
2   3   0.9
```

If I run the code with this example, it shows I have 1 community! while the weight of the link from node 1 to 2 is zero and I should have 2 communities. So it is not considered the weight of the network. What should I do?

Comment: I used also for a bigger network (directed and weighted). No difference are between the results of these codes:    1) weights="if_present" 2) weights=True  3)weights=False  4) I delete the world weights so it was just:  g1=Graph.Read_Ncol("1.txt",names=("node1","node2","weigths"),directed=True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the infomap parameter brackets you need to specify edge weights as follows:

```
G = Graph.Read_Ncol('1.txt', names=('node1', 'node2', 'weights'), directed=True)
comms = G.community_infomap(edge_weights = 'weights')
```

You can verify this makes a difference by subsequently checking the modularity after adding the weights function:

```
q = G.modularity(comms)
print(q)
```

My own data's differences in modularity after leaving the parameter blank, then adding edge_weights:

```
comms = G.community_infomap()
q = G.modularity(comms)
print(q)
0.6460833771434323

comms = G.community_infomap(edge_weights = 'weight')
q = G.modularity(comms)
print(q)
0.6130915761568664
```

If this doesn't work, then convert your datafile to GML without titles, and read it in as follows:

```
G = Graph.Read_GML('Only2001_15Removed.gml')
comms = G.community_infomap(edge_weights = 'weight')
```

Comment: At least for `python-igraph  0.8.2`, infomap is treating my weights (type=float) as binary, If the weights are <=0, I get one set of communities, and if the weights are >0, I get another. It doesn't matter what weights I use within these cutoffs (eg., 1 & 1e-30 generate the same number of communities: 148).  Any idea why?